# Sync Adapter in Android

Tags: android, adapter, synchronization

I am writing a custom sync Adapter. After adding a Account it will show the Databases to be synced, Based on the declaration in the Adapter.xml for ex Sync Contacts , Sync Calender.

Can i Customize these names.

Thanks
vikas bisla

Comment: NO it cannot be customized to change these one has to change in the framework.

Comment: Can u plz provide solution for the following link:[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326366/android-updating-contact-details-on-a-webserver-via-user-login

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the label tag for your provider in AndroidManifest.xml, for instance:

```
provider android:name="ItemProvider" android:authorities="com.yourApp.ItemProvider" android:label="All data" android:syncable="true"
```

Cheers